# For what reasons might a full professor lose tenure?

Tags: united-states, professorship, tenure-track, administration

Recently, a full professor at my university lost their tenure and had their employment with the university terminated. I have never heard of a tenured faculty member "being fired" before. I am not sure why this happened or what the former professor did that resulted in this outcome.

I know that assistant professors can be denied tenure for poor performance. But for what reasons might a full professor (or an associate professor) lose tenure?

(In this question I use US-centric academic ranks. An assistant professor is tenure-track, an associate professor is tenured, and a full professor is tenured with a slight increase in pay/benefits/responsibilities.)

Comment: Given your final note, I've added the US tag because it's probably not possible to give a general answer (in some countries revoke of tenure may be subjected to local laws).

Comment: You use US-centric position names, sure. But is your question entirely about the US? Exactly what "tenure" means surely differs from country to country; some places, such as the UK, have no concept of tenure at all. If you're asking about the whole world, this is surely too broad.

Comment: Just for accuracy, you can be associate without tenure, but the requirements for tenure as associate are different (harder), so people usually get tenured then bumped to associate in one swoop.

Comment: There are US universities, like Harvard, where full professors do not or not always have tenure.

Comment: In my discipline, an example would be: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergio_Verd%C3%BA

Answer (score 30):

The details are likely institution (and or state) specific.

From the [University of New Mexico Faculty Handbook](http://handbook.unm.edu/policies/section-b/b5.html) one sees that the options there are:

1. "Adequate Cause", including academic incompetence, neglect of duty, serious violation of policy, serious crime, loss of license (medical), or other serious deficiency.
2. Financial emergency - that is, the university runs out of money to pay them.
3. Termination of the program/department.
4. Health reasons (permanent disability with no reasonable accommodation possible).

Comment: Note that financial emergency isn't a true dismissal, but a furlough. The university has to hire back furloughed faculty before anybody else. This is true in most places, and is also affected by collective bargaining agreements (unions).

Comment: @user71659 - For sure, but if a college shuts down (perhaps unlikely for a state school) there is not chance to be rehired.

Comment: It's an important protection to prevent the case where they want to fire somebody, so the Dean withholds 1 FTE's worth of money to the department, and oops, financial emergency.

Comment: Is seducing the students included in point 1?

Comment: @RedSonja - one would have to carefully check the wording throughout the faculty handbook, and likely see if there are any examples at the institution. Likely the use "serious" rather than a long list to allow for  judgement (good or bad) in a process.

Comment: @user71659 In the case of the quoted school that's limited to a two year period for that exact position. If - as is common with financial trouble - multiple places get assimilated into one that wouldn't even apply. So yes, it is true dismissal, just one where conditions apply.

Comment: @JonCuster Public schools are more susceptible to financial emergencies and department closures because their budget is allocated year-to-year from taxes, and is essentially dependent on the economy. Private schools won't see a major drop in operating funds unless enrollment significantly drops, besides the large endowments they sit on.

Comment: @user71659 - I think you over estimate how big of an endowment many small liberal arts colleges have. The Ivies may have billions, but many have much less than that. You might consider the drama (and lawsuits) at Sweet Briar College (endowment of around $74M) over the last few years. And, big state universities get a surprisingly small amount of support from the state (UC Berkeley is somewhere around 15% of the budget is from the state).

Comment: @JonCuster The problem with your observation of Berkeley is that budget dollars are not interchangeable. Faculty's 9-month salaries, and accompanying overhead, must come from tuition and fees, which is fundamentally State funds. A professor cannot support their own position on grant money outside summer. On top of that auxiliary slice is off limits, as are big chunks like medical center services. Also in the UC System, all overhead goes directly into the state's general fund then are apportioned by legislature, so it is subject to political factors, including unequal returns to campuses.

Comment: @user71659 - Note that tuition and fees are not allocated by the state.

Comment: @user71659 - but we are straying far from the original intent of my answer. If the university is broke, it shuts down and doesn't pay anyone anymore.

Comment: @JonCuster Not in the UC System, as in most public schools. The legislature says you have x resident enrollment and $y state funds to do that with. The difference between resident tuition and non-resident tuition is the effective taxpayer subsidy ($29k in UC right now).

Comment: @RedSonja  Obviously, it *should* be adequate grounds for loss of tenure *and* dismissal. Yet one hears and reads of so many cases where under- and post-grad students have been seduced by their professor, often in the professor's rooms/office in the evening - the latter surely adding to the seriousness of the offence.

Answer (score 18):

Even tenured professors are required to adhere to a certain level of standards. They are given *academic* freedoms, but not *complete* freedoms.

Committing a felony could in many cases lead to your dismissal, regardless of if you have tenure or not. Rape, murder, sexual assault, multiple DUIs, etc. all could result in being fired (even if you have tenure).

Committing fraud with department/grant money would also likely lead to being dismissed.

Comment: I heard about a professor back in the 1990s that defrauded his postdocs out of money (he told them they had to deposit their wages into his account, and he will pay them, and in the process he cut himself some of the money). The university caught up to him at some point, and they told him that they will let him keep the money if he resigns quietly and never comes back. Or something like that. Not exactly getting fired, but close enough, and I guess a lot of headache saved for the department in terms of de-tenure process being skipped.

Answer (score 12):

Traditionally, tenured faculty can only be dismissed on non-academic grounds, such as the reasons discussed in @Vladhagen's answer.

But that is not the reality everywhere. Universities that have a post-tenure review (at least in some cases) reserve the right to dismiss faculty if, say, their research output slows down too much. See, for example, [the post-tenure review policy at University of Colorado](https://www.colorado.edu/facultyaffairs/career-milestones/post-tenure-review): "Possible sanctions include...revocation of tenure and dismissal."

Answer (score 1):

When a professor receives tenure, it means that s/he may not "let go" in order to  be replaced by the university by another individual, even if younger or "cheaper." Thus, a tenured professor may be terminated only for "standalone" reasons.

1. Financial reasons leading to the discontinuation of the professor's department or at least courses, without the possibility of the professor's reasonably being transferred to a new department or courses; one or more positions was eliminated and not replaced.
2. Violation of academic or legal standards against plagiarism, sexual harassment, drug use or commission of other civil crimes, usually felonies, such as fraud or assault. These are typically violations of university policy as well as civil law.
3. Possibly minor "violations" that go to the heart of the academic experience, such as repeatedly not showing up for class, and teaching far fewer hours than courses require.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add something relevant to the USA academic dismissal landscape - and probably relevant to other countries also.

Some universities are the property of, and operate under the control of, one or other church. For example, the USA has 244 catholic church governed universities - of which 60 are Jesuit governed. There may be other universities in which certain departments (e.g. theology, divinity) are under the auspices of one or other religious denomination.

It has been known that professors of theology have been dismissed ([and their dismissal upheld in courts later](https://ie.vlex.com/vid/mcgrath-and-ruairc-v-793408705)) after making utterances in conflict with prevailing church dogma. In Germany, [Hans Kung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_K%C3%BCng#Career) was on the point of getting booted out of his job within the Institute for Ecumenical Studies after sharing his views on papal infallibility and celibacy. Luckily, in his case the University of Tubingen stepped in to secularize his Institute within the university and save his job. But others have not been so fortunate.

Obviously, such removals of tenure may only occur in departments over which the denomination has authority. So a Jewish lecturer in economics in John Carroll University cannot be summarily fired for referring occasionally to the Vatican as "a terrible waste of money". He could however find himself subject to a cold war campaign amongst colleagues envious of his talents or courage who would make affectations of orthodoxy in favour of the university management.

Comment: -1 Your last paragraph seems to be anti-Catholic. Are you referring to a particular case? In the third paragraph both examples seem to be from Europe in the 1970s, but you said you were talking about the USA academic dismissal landscape.

Comment: The examples provided in para 3 were in the public domain in the 70s and 80s. I didn't google dismissals from Episcopalian, Methodist, Baptist or Presbyterian ethos colleges. The final para posits a (very, considering academics' normally hypersensitive political antennae) hypothetical scenario but with a plausible consequence. I think a similar scenario could occur in a college with a Jewish ethos but which employs Gentiles in secular department positions.

Comment: In that case, the final para is definitely anti-Catholic. The invented quotation and the last sentence are gratuitous.

Comment: @Oliver882  I think you are being too sensitive on behalf of the churches here. Looking through Google there are recent cases of academics and administrators being removed from positions in universities founded by other denominations, usually on grounds of doctrinal differences. Human beings are human beings, regardless of faith and path.